# Javascript split html content

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview, split, epub

I am creating an ePub reader on IOS. Basically,  I use uiwebview to load the xhtml files.
Every time  page turn， I need to load the file with uiwebview then call javascript to scroll to the right offset.  Here is a problem, some xhtml file is big (like > 2MB) that it cost too much time to load. Thus the page turn animation is not so smooth.
So I am thinking I could load the xhtml once with uiwebviewA , and each time page turn, I create another uiwebviewB and grab the needed html content(like second page) from uiwebviewA. In this way, I could limite the html into small size and the page turn animation should be smooth.
My question is that is there any open source javascript library can do the job?
Any comments is appreciated!!

Comment: jQuery Mobile deals great with your problem, it uses one HTML file with multiple pages defined in it, so give it a try : [JQM](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: "What is a page" It is hard to detect what fits on a page. Different fonts, sizes, images, layout, spacing, content, etc.

Comment: I use the -webkit-columns to format html content in to columns, so a page means a column

Comment: @NikolaNinkovic Thank you, I'll check.

Comment: Yes I figured you are using the columns, but you are missing the point. Those columns are figured out on the browser with the content. How would you know how much data is needed to fill up that column with that request? [I wrote a reader, I know the issues]

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253702/epub-reader-to-handle-big-html-file?

Comment: @torazaburo no, this question is trying to figure out a solution with Javascript. Do you have any thoughts on this question?

Comment: @epascarello yes, you are absolutely right. I don't know how to split the html content, That's why I post this question. Since you wrote a reader before, Can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: It is impossible to fetch exact pages. You need to write the backend to give you chunks and preload them.

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean by backend? you mean the physical file? cut the physical file into small parts?

Comment: backend aka php/cgi/java/c# or you can manually cut it up.

Comment: @epascarello ebook reader like iBooks, santaz is not having these backend, but they run ePub smoothly. I think there must be some tricky to cut big files into small pieces. I think there should be two ways to cut.  (1)Physically cut file into small pieces. (2)Retrieve Dom with js to get needed html content. Both of them require a well designed library to cut. Which way did you choose? And how to cut?

Comment: iBooks is not an html application. It is a native iphone app so it has better control. The thing is you can not just fetch a file from the server and not have to load it into memory somehow to figure out how to break it up. Since you are using CSS to do the paging it is basically impossible for you to know where the page divisions are to fetch. You could do something with a special break point in the markup that you can pull apart with a reg exp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no meaningful, well-defined way to split an HTML document in the way you seem to be describing. You are confusing two very different things: (1) splitting the rendering into page-sized chunks, and (2) splitting the HTML source. To put it a different way, there is no algorithm I can imagine that would split an HTML file into pieces, such that the sequential composition of the rendered pieces was identical to the rendering of the original HTML file. In other words, in order to figure out how to split the HTML, assuming it is even possible, you'd have to do much or all of the work involved in rendering the page, which would defeat the entire purpose.

You should abandon the notion of splitting the HTML. Ebook readers all paginate by essentially rendering the entire HTML document once, then "windowing" and "clipping" and "offsetting" or, in some cases, using CSS regions.

There are a couple of alternatives I can think of, if I understand what you are trying to do.

1. Reduce the size of the input HTML files by pre-splitting them earlier in the
   workflow. For instance, in one project I know, the source (X)HTML files have bits of additional markup that tell a pre-processor where split them into individual files if desired, which in this case is a work-around for ebook readers that don't honor CSS `page-break-*` properties properly.
2. Pre-compute the rendering for next page as a graphic and
   use it for the page turning.
3. As already discussed, rethink your architecture of reloading the entire HTML document for every page in your book. If it is merely page turning effects that
   lead you to want to do that, then give them up.
4. Consider that many ebook readers provide a scrolling mode that does
   not require pagination, and some (eg Himawari Reader) provide **only**
   scrolling mode, which is actually something that some readers prefer.
   You can put out your scrolling version, and then do pagination in version 2.

Comment: Do you know any of open source reader which is providing scrolling mode? That would be helpful to me and save my time. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should really check this:

http://cubiq.org/swipeview

And this demo that does exactly what you asked for:

http://cubiq.org/dropbox/SwipeView/demo/ereader/

It takes a text (book) and paginates the text to fit the screen size.

I tested the demo in Android and iOS and it works great!!